# Getting error when creating ImagesController in MVC 4

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, model, controller, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to create an ImagesController in MVC4 like this

[image]

But I keep getting this error.

[image]

Had no problem creating controller for PeopleController using this class

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Affair> Affairs { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `File` property on the `Image` class. Because EntityFramework won't understand the type `HttpPostedFileBase` and can't store it in the DB and the controller generator is smart enough to check this. Altough the error message doesn't tell you what is the problem. To fix this you should rewrite your property to use a byte array:

```
public class Image
{
    ...
    public byte[] File { get; set; }
}
```

And then the controller generation should work. And you can add your own image upload action, something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(Image image, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(image).State = EntityState.Modified;
        image.File = new byte[file.ContentLength];
        file.InputStream.Read(image.File, 0, file.ContentLength); 
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(image);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I was trying to follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351071/how-do-upload-and-associate-an-image-with-another-class-simultaneously-in-mvc3. Would you happen to know which helpers i would use?

Comment: The generator `Contoller with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework` only supports model types which are compatible with EF. If you want to have `HttpPostedFileBase` (in this case your Image class will be a ViewModel not a model) then you have to create manually the controller or maybe the [MvcScaffolding package](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/) can help.